# phpspreadsheet : getCalculatedValue don't get the calculated value

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

I'm using the library phpspreadsheet, and I have a problem on one of my cell.

In my excel I got :

|  | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 12% (calculated by excel with complicated formula) | 12% (formula : =C8) |

The cell D8 value is "=C8" but when I read it with getCalculatedValue I don't get the value of C8 (12%) but literally "=C8".

```
<?php
$my_spreadsheet->getSheetByName('first sheet')->getCell("D8")->isFormula(); #true
$my_spreadsheet->getSheetByName('first sheet')->getCell("D8")->getCalculatedValue(); #=C8
$my_spreadsheet->getSheetByName('first sheet')->getCell("D8")->getFormattedValue(); #=C8
$my_spreadsheet->getSheetByName('first sheet')->getCell("D8")->getValue(); #=C8
```

The formula are mostly well calculated, but I have some cell that are not calculated like the one above, they are all formatted as percent.

Did I have a corrupted cell or did I miss a parameter?

P.S. Sorry for the english

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you use

$Reader->setReadDataOnly( true );

this says read only the data and that you can't use the calculation more information see [here.](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/calculation-engine/)

Remove above line or set it to false.

A other possibility is that you not configuration the calculation engine right. Please check link above.